# Why won't GIF slow down with kCGImagePropertyGIFDelayTime

Tags: ios, swift, image-processing, cgimage

Using [Rob Mayoff's answer to create GIF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14915138/create-and-and-export-an-animated-gif-via-ios), I've adapted his code to the following in Swift.

```
let kFrameCount:Int = 6

let frames:NSNumber = NSNumber(float: 20000.0) //No matter what number I place here...GIF runs at same speed

let fileProperties = [kCGImagePropertyGIFLoopCount as String: 0]
let frameProperties = [kCGImagePropertyGIFDelayTime as String: frames]

let documentsUrl =  NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0] as! NSURL
let fileURL = documentsUrl.URLByAppendingPathComponent("animated.gif")

var destination: CGImageDestination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL(fileURL, kUTTypeGIF, kFrameCount, nil)
var destination2: Void = CGImageDestinationSetProperties(destination, fileProperties)

for i in 0..<kFrameCount {
   CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, imagessss[i].CGImage, frameProperties)
}

if (!CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination)) {
        println("fail")
}

println(fileURL)

let activityVC: UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [fileURL], applicationActivities: nil)
self.presentViewController(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This creates the GIF. But no matter what amount I place as the `float`, 20000.0 or 0.01, the GIF runs at the same **DelayTime**. Also if I change the value in `fileProperties` from 0 to any other number, the GIF still does a continuous loop.

I feel the error lies in the line

```
var destination2: Void = CGImageDestinationSetProperties(destination, fileProperties)
```

or my declaration of `fileProperties` and `frameProperties`

Does Anyone know why my `fileProperties` and `frameProperties` are not effecting the GIF?

P.S. I can effectively slowdown the gif by increasing the frames and lacing the `imagessss` array with duplicate images, But this isn't ideal.

Comment: Interesting piece of code about the delay problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17824564/2227743

Comment: shouldn't the delayTime be an innate property of the GIF file, decided at writing?

Comment: Look at this example: https://gist.github.com/mayoff/4969104 search for kCGImagePropertyGIFDelayTime

Comment: @MaticOblak this is the same code as the link i provided. that I adapted the Swift version from

Comment: Oh, great then. But you wrote it wrong. You are missing the other constant which wraps the value you are setting. Check again..

Comment: yes that is very possible, I don't know ObjC and Swift is my only, and still very new, language. if you could point me to which line? i spent 14 hours yesterday just to produce this.

Comment: @EricD. So are you saying that my GIF might be writing with the correct delayTime but depending on what 'program' it is expressed 'on', the frame duration might be expressed at a default rate?

Comment: Oh *I* am not saying anything. ;) But the answer I mentioned does, and indeed I believe it's true, apps can change the delay/rate of a GIF. I have no expertise on this, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the `kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary` level in your properties.

Change you properties to:

`let fileProperties = [kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary as String: [kCGImagePropertyGIFLoopCount as String: 0]]
let frameProperties = [kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary as String: [kCGImagePropertyGIFDelayTime as String: frames]]`

(I'm using Xcode 6.4)